# Export Selected Rows from CrossTable in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to export data as TSV from my crosstable in Spotfire using IronPython.

Currently it exports the whole Crosstable:

```
from System.IO import Path, File, StreamWriter
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import CrossTablePlot

#Export CrossTable data to the temp file
writer = StreamWriter("C:/temp/data.tsv")
vTable.As[CrossTablePlot]().ExportText(writer)
```

However, I want to export only the rows I have marked. Is there a way to do this quickly without a lookup using Datatable methods?